# Unable to set gofmt-args in Go mode

Tags: formatting, golang

I am unable to set gofmt arguments to consume the following arguments

`-tabs=false -tabwidth=2 -w=true`

When I set the variable gofmt-args, I get the following error **Invalid read syntax: "Trailing garbage following expression"**.

If I give just one argument such as  `-tabwidth=2`, I get the error **Value ‘-tabwidth=2’ does not match type repeat of gofmt-args**

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you tried to set `gofmt-args`?

Comment: I just used M-x set-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you tried passing an unquoted string to set `gofmt-args`. `gofmt-args`'s type is a list of strings, so that is what you need to give it. You can set it like this:

```
(setq gofmt-args '("-tabs=false" "-tabwidth=2" "-w=true"))
```

If you are setting it interactively, its probably easiest to use `M-x customize-variable RET gofmt-args RET`. That will give you an interactive UI for adding and removing elements from the list and you don't need to worry about quoting.

Comment: Thanks @psanford. That indeed works. customize-variable is much much better than set-variable.